# Update a DataGridView on Runtime

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I just have a quick question. Whenever I Insert something into my C# interface (which is connected to a SQL database), I get the message of "Saved Data" that I programmed (and it saves the data in the database), but my DataGridView doesn't updates unless I close the application and run it again.

My code is:

```
private void frmCatalogoMunicipios_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd.Connection = conexion;
    }

    private void frmCatalogoMunicipios_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CargaEstados();
        CargaDataGridView();
    }

    private void CargaEstados()
    {
        conexion.Open();
        txtNomMun.Focus();
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT cveestado, nombre FROM tbestados", conexion);
            da.Fill(ds, "FillDropDown");
            cbEstado.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
            cbEstado.ValueMember = "CveEstado";
            cbEstado.DataSource = ds.Tables["FillDropDown"];
            conexion.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void CargaDataGridView()
    {
        conexion.Open();
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT m.cvemunicipio, m.nombre AS NombreA, e.nombre AS NombreB FROM tbMunicipios m INNER JOIN tbEstados e ON m.CveEstado = e.CVeEstado";
            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rd.GetValue(0), rd.GetValue(1), rd.GetValue(2));
            }
            conexion.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }


conexion.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into tbmunicipios (nombre, cveestado) values ('" + txtNomMun.Text + "', '" + cbEstado.SelectedValue.ToString() + "')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Clone();
                MessageBox.Show("Datos Guardados", "Mensaje");
                conexion.Close();
                Nuevo();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

**EDIT**

I found the answer myself: like @Obama said. I have to call CargarDataGridView(), BUT before that i deleted all my rows with dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

So, my final code is:

```
                conexion.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into tbmunicipios (nombre, cveestado) values ('" + txtNomMun.Text + "', '" + cbEstado.SelectedValue.ToString() + "')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Clone();
                MessageBox.Show("Datos Guardados", "Mensaje");
                conexion.Close();
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                CargaDataGridView();
                Nuevo();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

Comment: Have you a method which refresh the datagridview? if so which one i don't understand spanish very well :)

Comment: Thanks @Obama, I already answer the question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after `MessageBox.Show("Datos Guardados", "Mensaje");`
call `CargaDataGridView();`

Comment: Oh, thanks... I forgot to mention it; if I do this, it updates my datagridview, but the old datagridview stays there. For example, If i i have in my database the records 1 thru 4, and i insert 5, my datagridview will have records 1 thru 4 and 1 thru 5, so it has 9 records, when i want to display 4

Comment: you need to clear the rows of the datagridview when refreshing (in the refresh method) CargaDataGridView(); by dataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); , if you think i helped you accept my answer :)

Comment: Hahaha, I got to the same conclusion :D BUT I'll accept it as an answer anyways, THANKS A LOT, @Obama